# ISO vs Small on hard disk Drive

Tags: hard-drive, iso-image

usually a hard disk drive full of small files works slower, the files also move slower in other disks or whatever...

i have some GB of files that i just need them as "IS", no need to edit something or whatever...just accessing them while if need  they're mostly samples for music, small wave files here and there, soundfonts, some sound libraries etc....

i was wondering if i would get any benefits if i was making a HUGE ISO file and accessing them from a virtual drive or whatever.. i don't need to share in network or whatever, just working locally with them.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

If the idea is to save space, then a ZIP file is more efficient, although updating
a huge ZIP file is painful.

If the purpose is to speed up the access, then leaving the files on the disk as they
are now is the most efficient. Any ISO or ZIP file will have slower access time,
since you are in effect accessing two disks : The physical disk and then the ISO disk.

The only real speedup will be to get a faster disk. An SSD would be best.

Comment: i am not trying to save space.... if that was the concept indeed, a rar or zip file would be the best choice though the updates or whatever in this case would be like a hell in terms of time. 
i need to be able access the files from 3rd party applications (Samplers etc) as IS, as i explained.. i just wonder if there would be any benefit from having them all inside 1 file than having them indexed in Hard disk as 8293492384 files.
SSD is out of question... for the size i need the cost would be way high (like 1TB) 

thank you for your time :)

Comment: The price of 1TB SSD has gone down below $100.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. 
By using ISOs and ZIPs you are basically creating a nested file system because the internal ISO and ZIP structure is basically a file system itself.

You are putting less load on your file system by just operating on one file.
The disadvantage is handling. You have to unpack your samples p.e.. 
Using the search function of a file system your ISO is contained in the search will usually stop at file level, so there is no search inside the ISO file unless you mount it as separate file system.